# How can I use a Canon EOS-1d with Windows 7, since Canon utilities aren't available?

Tags: canon, software, windows-7

I have a canon EOS-1D which came with utilities for windows 98. There are not utilities available for windows 7. Can my camera be reprogrammed to work with utilities available for windows 7 and if so who can do this?

Comment: What functions of the utility do you especially need? Is it the import? The tethering? Knowing this will allow people to give more helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

I've never bothered with the Canon EOS Utility (except to change the copyright info in the camero, not that that is that big a deal anyhow.)

I've had great success using Adobe Lightroom. Sure, it cost something but it is just amazing. If you can't get the EOS to work in emulation as AJ suggests, look into Lightroom. (Note, this won't help if you need tethering, thanks Bart!)

Comment: Lightroom does not support tethering to the extent that the EOS utility does. This might be a deal breaker.

Comment: True enough, that would certainly be a problem if you needed that.

Answer (score 1):

There is support for the EOS-1D on Windows XP.  Windows 7 supports running a virtual machine that can run Windows XP applications that are incompatible with Windows 7.  You should be able to install the software for the EOS-1D on the Windows XP VM and then use that directly from within Windows 7.  For more details on using Windows 7's XP mode, I'd suggest checking on SuperUser as that part is really more of a general computing question.

It may require a [firmware update](http://web.canon.jp/imaging/EOS1D/1D_firmware-e.html) to the EOS-1D depending on what version it is running.

Answer (score 0):

There are Canon utilities available, for your camera, for every version of Windows since XP.  Download the package from:-

http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/cameras/Digital_SLR/EOS_1D.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:14-1092133&page=1&type=download

It's called an "update" but is, in fact, a complete install of the application.  You will need your original CD/DVD or a previous install.

Note:  The requirement for a previous install is easy to circumvent.  The install routine simply checks for the existence of a small number of registry entries that a previous installation would have created.  These can easily be added by hand (I have a .reg file with them somewhere which I can dig out/recreate if you need help with this).

Note: The requirement for a previous install is easy to circumvent for OS X also, just right click, show package Contents, dig around, and you'll find the full app.

--------------------update-------------------

Confirming what AJ Henderson said, it looks like the EOS utility for the EOS-1D stopped at XP:-

http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/cameras/Digital_SLR/EOS_1D.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:14-727693&page=2&type=download

But this should run in Windows 7 and 8 (you may need to set compatibility mode on the shortcut to the application).  If it doesn't work, somebody (I hesitate to volunteer, as I don't have an EOS-1D available for testing) could use the EOS SDK to write a new app to run in the later versions of Windows.  I intend to write a Windows 8.1 version in the coming weeks/months, but that would be against the .DLL for the newer EOS models (including mine, call me selfish)...

Comment: Just realised that's the download for DPP not the EOS Utility - which may not get you the software to pull images from your camera.  I'll dig around a bit more and see what I can find.